# Which item in an access form listbox object have I double-clicked on?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, listbox, double-click

I have a listbox in my form which has MultiSelect as Simple.

I want to be able to use the item that I double click on in the lst_DblClick Sub. Something like `Me.lst.Clicked`.

There may be other items already selected otherwise I know that I can loop through the items and use `Me.lst.Selected(i)` or similar. I'm having trouble identifying the one most recently clicked. Other than storing this somewhere which seems massive sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut I'm not sure where to go with it.

I'm already looping through the items on a Click event of the same form which is why some may be already selected from that.

As a side note I'm unsure over whether what I put in here will work at all as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837260.aspx tells me that the click event will fire as well as the double. I'm not opening a message box or similar with the single click so hoping it will still fire.

Comment: have you tried using `ListBox1_Click` event handler to keep track of the item selected in some public variable?

Comment: I've not but this was the sledgehammer approach I was alluding to. I'm envisaging there could be quite a few more items in the list as it gets used more and more in my team.

Comment: well as long as _"identifying the one most recently clicked"_ listbox item issue is concerned I couldn't think of anything else than "`ListBox1_Click event`+ public variable" approach, which I wouldn't call a "sledgehammer" one at all, standing the issue.

Comment: I gotta agree with user.  If you're concerned about the order they're selected in, the only option is to write an array after each selection.  There's no LastClicked property or anything like that, it's either selected or it's not..

Comment: Thanks both, I guess I was just asking in case there was another way anyone could think of. I'll implement that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do what you are wanting without writing a bunch of code.

When an Access Listbox has 1 or more items selected (whether using "Simple" or "Extended" multi-select mode), there are multiple methods to get at the data.

If you want to know the currently selected item in the listbox (the item last clicked), you would reference that with the .[Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834793.aspx) property without specifying the Row parameter.  The Index parameter is 0 based, so column 1 in your listbox is referenced as 0 with the .Column property, column 2 is referenced as 1, etc.

```
Me.lst.Column(0)
```

So, for example, assuming that the first column in your listbox contains a unique row identifier that you are wanting to act on in the double-click event, you could reference that value in your double-click event using the line of code shown above and then act on that value.

When you want to loop through all of the selected items in your multi-select listbox, you could do so separately in the following manner by enumerating through the .[ItemsSelected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823015.aspx) property.

```
Dim varItm As Variant
Dim ID As Long
Dim AName As String

For Each varItm In Me.lst.ItemsSelected
    'Loop and do something with one or more values from each selected
    'row in the listbox
    ID = Me.lst.Column(0, varItm)    'get the value from the 1st column
    AName = Me.lst.Column(2, varItm) 'get the value from the 3rd column
Next varItm
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm about to leave work now and I'll try this tomorrow hence me only upvoting this for now. Based on tomorrow's trials I may accept it.